# Creating a box/cell to put text on an image in html css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a box that I can add some text and an image to
[image]

The above image is the setup I already have. I want to add a box where the pink box is. So far my code is:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#wrapper {
    display:table;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
#wrapper .row {
    display:table-row;
}
#wrapper .cell {
    display:table-cell;
    width:100%;
}
#header .cell {
    height:55px;
    vertical-align:top;
    background:#ffffff;

    /*good color: fbf9f9*/



   }
#body, #body.cell {
    height:100%;
}
#body .cell {
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
}
.innerdiv {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    z-index: -2;
}
.centeredImage {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
   .imageCorner {

    display: block;
}

.right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    padding: 2px 0 0 0;

}

.right2 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 60px;
    padding: 2px 0 0 0;

}

.right3{

    position: absolute;
    left:5px;
    padding: 4px 0 0 0;

}
```

html:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header" class="row">
        <div class="cell"><img class="right3" src="dl.png"><img class="right2" src="twitter.png"><img class="right" src="fblogo2.png"></div>
    </div>
     <div id="body" class="row">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="innerdiv">
                <img class="imageCorner" src="logo.png" />
            </div>
            <p class="centeredImage">
                <img src="smallslide1.png" >
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
```

I want the box to stay in the correct position regardless of screen size. Not sure how to go about this, tried creating some divs but couldn't get it in the right position. Could someone give me some pointers on how to do this please? fiddle:  jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=4d09vpG7p2

Comment: Your jsfiddle link not working.

Comment: @ketan you can't see the code or the link is broken?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=4d09vpG7p2